# Laravel Mews captcha_img() does not return on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, captcha

I'm using Mews/Captcha package with a Laravel 5.5. application.

I'm implementing a contact form where the user fills it out, enters in Captcha data, and submits it.  All of that works.  If you go to the form, the captcha image appears.  If you refresh the page, a new captcha image appears.  If you try to submit the form without the captcha or an incorrect captcha, it fails.  If you submit with the correct captcha it succeeds.

The issue I am having is with the refresh button in case the user wants to change the image.  For the life of me, I can't get it to return the image, even though I've seen numerous examples that claim to work that are using similar code.  What happens is that the current captcha image is replaced by blank space.

Here's the code for the button:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#reload').on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/reload-captcha',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#captchadiv").html(data.captcha);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the code further down the page where the captcha image and buttons are:

```
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="button reload" id="reload">Refresh</button></td>
            <td><div id="captchadiv">{!! captcha_img('flat') !!}</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="captcha">Captcha</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="captcha" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Captcha" name="captcha">
                @if ($errors->has('captcha'))
                    <span class="textRed">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('captcha') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif</td>
        </tr>
```

Here's the code for the response:

```
    public function reloadCaptcha()
    {
        return response()->json(['captcha'=> captcha_img('flat')]);
    }
```

Now, if I replace `captcha_img('flat')` with some text and click the button, it behaves as expected and replaces the previous image with the text.  Also, if the text supplied is html code that calls a static image from a path in the public directory, it also works.

So either one of two things is going on:

1. the captcha_img() function is failing during the response step.  So nothing returns.
2. the javascript in the form is failing to extract the image from the returned json object.

I'm guessing the issue is #1.  Somehow the controller is unable to call the captcha_img() function while the main php/html can.  And I have no idea why that would be.

Note that in my experiments, I put in an alert which showed the data and the status, and the data displayed an "object" and the status was "success".

### Update

I gave up.  For whatever reason, I just can't get it to work and I can't afford to spend any more time on it right now.  I ended up going with making the button reload the entire page rather than try to generate just a new captcha image to insert into the html.

Comment: I checked your link and changed it to flat,mini,default,math and inverse type of captcha and it's working fine.

Comment: your /reload-captcha return this : {
  "captcha": "<img src=/images/wped/earth2.png>"
}

Comment: I was experimenting with various things to try and pin down why the reload wasn't working.  That's why there was the earth2.png reference to see if I could swap out the captcha image with a static image.  You just happened to check it when I was playing around with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change return function reload captcha to this:

```
public function reloadCaptcha()
{
    return captcha_img('flat');
}
```

And then change refresh event script to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reload').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/reload-captcha',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#captchadiv").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```